# column names as variables while creating table

Tags: python, sqlite

Iam new to python sqlite, and I have a problem with create table query.

I need to create a table, but I have the column names of the table as a list.

```
columnslist = ["column1", "column2", "column3"]
```

Now, I have to create a table `MyTable` with the above columns. But the problem is, I won't know before hand how may columns are there in `columnslist`

Is it possible to create a table with the number of and name of columns given in columnslist and its syntax?

Comment: `len(columnslist)` gives you the length.

Comment: `len(columnslist)` is a number of names in list. `columnslist[0]`...`columnslist[x]`...`columnslist[len(columnslist)-1]` are names of particular list element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert your list to tuple and use `str.format`:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE table_name {}'''.format(tuple(column_list)))
```

Comment: Wow!! It never occured to me to use string format. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is fantastic, you saved my day