# How to name a table & rows using variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

So I'm trying to figure out how to name a table together with rows using variables. I already found out the part how to name the table using a variable. And I also tried using the methods from: 
[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155021/column-names-as-variables-while-creating-table)
together with the code I already have, but that didn't work out.

To make it a bit more clear:

```
tableName = "fruits"
rowName1 = "apple"
rowName2 = "pineapple"
rowName3 = "cranberry"
rowName4 = "banana"
```

And use all of this in a CREATE TABLE.

Code that I already have: (Where I use a variable to name the table)

```py
sql_cmd = '''CREATE TABLE {}(test, test2, test3, test4)'''.format(tableName)

dataBaseConnection.execute(sql_cmd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you pass the command to the connection to the database, not the cursor, and never commit the change. Your total code (minus the variable definitions) should look like this:

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect("yourdatabase.db")
c=conn.cursor()
sql_cmd = '''CREATE TABLE {}({}, {}, {}, {})'''.format(
    tableName, rowName1, rowName2, rowName3, rowName4)
c.execute(sql_cmd)
conn.commit()
```

(I also used the .format functionality to take into account your variables).